# decrypt db from asset folder

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, assets

I searched a lot. but they not worked for me.
I have an encrypted database in asset folder.  How can I decrypt in for copy to data folder?
I know how can copy db from asset to data in normal situation. But now I have encrypted database in asset folder.

Comment: How was the database encrypted?  It sounds like you just need to decrypt it with your decryption key.

Comment: I decrypted it via program from site: https://dbconvert.com/ when you want to convert database from sql to db you can type number for encrypt. so how can I decrypt in in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with  dbconvert.com but as far as I can tell the site you used has nothing to do encryption/decryption.  It appears to *convert* from one format to another... so assuming you converted any format to SQLite (which is what Android uses) then you should just be able to copy the database from your assets folder when the app is first run and from then on use it just like any other SQLite database.  There are plenty of examples/code for this on the Internet and also Stack Overflow, for example: [How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application)